# “Which is to” or “What to” - which one is more accurate?

Tags: word-choice

Between the two sentences, which one is more accurate and why?

1. Grammarly vs Prowritingaid – Which is to Choose?
2. Grammarly vs Prowritingaid – What to Choose?

Comment: Why have you included ***is to*** after ***which***, but not after ***what**?* Was that just a transcription error, or did you specifically ***intend*** that to be part of the "difference" being queried?

Comment: It's not transcription error. Both passed the error check in grammarly, and I'm not sure if there's any better 3rd

Comment: As I said when you first asked this on ELU, neither of your texts are sentences. They're just "noun phrases", and there's no point in thinking a software-based grammar checker can tell you anything about where they can or can't be used. But *usually* we stick with ***which*** when all possible choices are contextually obvious (choose *one of them*), and use ***what*** for more general contexts (choose *anything*).

Answer (score 0):

"Which is to choose" will pass a grammar check because it can work as an appositive modifier, i.e.: "Making a decision, which is to choose between two things, can be hard." That said, even in its 'correct' usage, it's clumsy and serves the function of adding clarification when it would be better to write with clarity that doesn't need the redundant repetition, i.e.: either the audience knows the word 'decision' and the sentence can be edited to 'Making a decision can be hard', or the audience does not know the word decision, and the sentence can be edited to 'Choosing between two things can be hard'. None of these examples are great writing, but I hope they're illustrative of the point.

"Which is to choose?" as a question on its own works grammatically only in a very narrow and strict understanding. The clue is in 'to' working in the infinitive of a verb, 'to choose' (rather than the preposition 'to town'). "Which is to choose?" asks, in the present, which of two or more known subjects, will be doing the choosing in some future yet to occur. But the question is addressed to an audience, not to the things being chosen between. "Who is to choose?" works a little better and is correct, because the "who" is more obviously a word we use, in this sense, for "things with the agency to decide" and the question itself implies that the agent who will be doing the deciding is unknown. It becomes more clear in the active voice, as almost always proves true. Imagine the sentence preceding the question were "A program has conflicting conditions for determining whether to execute a certain function." One could then ask the same question in either active or passive voice and be correct: "Which is to choose?" --> *"Which will choose?"* (replacing "choose" with "decide" makes this illustration clearer)

From your question though, and without any other background, the context I infer is that there are multiple options presented and you are either requesting your audience for the deciding input or describing them being in a state of not yet having made that decision, i.e.: "There are many options when deciding on a car to buy, but which to choose?" or "There are many options when deciding to buy a car, but what to choose?" I hope this difference also adds light to the linked "What vs. Which" question -- the first example shows deciding between a long but fixed list of vehicles and features, while the second implies a set of unknown outcomes, irrespective of however many or few possible outcomes might exist (i.e. "buy a car and risk being in an accident" / "not buy a car and save money but not be able to get to work as quickly" / "buy a car and see what happens" ....)